# Window panel button missing after upgrading 14.4

Tags: 14.04, panel, window

I am facing the following error top window panel button missing after upgrading and also when i installed  corebird  add the following  repo

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEKRN.png

Comment: After upgradrin what exactly? Upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04? Did you add a thir party repository to update Gnome?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: I think so what? Can you Please be more detailed in what did you do? Consider Edit your question.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I add  third party repository   when I installed  corebird                             side adds-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging

Comment: You'll have to purge the repositories and the packages installed from them(incluided corebord) in order to get back a proper Unity desktop.

Comment: ok how can i do that  i dont know the command

Answer (score 0):

In order to get back a proper Unity desktop, you'll have to purge the repositories and the packages installed from them(incluided corebird)

**How to purge a PPA**

Purging a PPA means not only to disable the PPA, but also to downgrade any packages you've upgraded from that PPA, to the version available in the official Ubuntu repositories.

To be able to purge a PPA, you need to install "ppa-purge":

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

To purge a PPA, you must use the following command:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:someppa/ppa
```

For example, to purge the Gnome's PPA's, you would use:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/how-to-use-launchpad-ppa-add-remove.html